# Using mutiprocessing.Pool for function inside for loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that takes in two arguments:

```
def vol(vor,p):
    return some_value
```

I call the function using a for loop:

```
infile = '/home/test.dat'
xx = np.genfromtxt(infile)
points = xx[:,0:3] # array with shape (4000,3)
galvor = Voronoi(points) 

ngal = np.shape(xx)[0] # just an integer
galden = np.zeros((ngal,)) 

for i in range(ngal):
    galden[i]= 1./vol(galvor,i)
```

Since this takes a lot of time, I tried to use Pool from multiprocessing in this way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes = 8)  # adjust to number of cores
    galden[i] = pool.map(vol, (galvor,range(ngal)))
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: vol() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

But as you can see, I have given two arguments to the function, i.e. `(galvor,range(ngal))`. 
Since `galvor` is not an iterable, I cannot use `zip(galvor,range(ngal))`.

Comment: Since map will unzip your iterable object, you need  `pool.map(vol, [(galvor, i) for i in range(ngal)])`

Comment: I still get the same error !

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. You also need to use `starmap`. `pool.starmap(vol, [(galvor, i) for i in range(ngal)])`

Comment: You mean, I should use `pool.starmap` instead of `pool.map` or both ?

Comment: You should use `starmap` instead but not both.

Comment: @Sraw: I don;t seem to have `starmap`

Comment: This is a new function since python 3.3. I suppose you are using 2.7? Unfortunately you may need modify your function to accept a tuple-like parameter and unzip it by your self.